# How to create Lotus form to both enter data and display the same information (Lotus Designer)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

Very new to Lotus designer.

I am trying to create a simple form with a field which is updated from time with additional information. I want the admin user to be able to update this information on the same form interface as the user viewing the information.

It appears I do not really understand how to get the form to display information entered into it previously.

I did Ctrl+shift view of the database and saw all the previous entries but I can not seem to get the form to display these information as well as allow me to append to them.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the online Domino Designer help - for instance the sections on designing forms:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT__FORMS.html

Answer (score 1):

A form is used to create a new document or to edit an existing document.  Since you say that you can see the previous entries, you must be creating a new document for each entry.

If you want to see and modify the contents of an existing document, you have to navigate to the document and open it for edit.

If you want the user to see a list of all the previous documents while he is creating a new one, you can add an embedded view to the form and use that to display data from the previous documents.

If you want all the information to be in a single document, then you need to stop creating new documents and just select the exiting document, open it for edit, make your changes, and re-save the document.